# Images in TableView animating when appear

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `TableView` and `Cells` inside of it can have different sizes/items. The user can also add an `image` to it. The weird thing is that when having `images` with different sizes the `images` start animating *weird*  when they appear.

It is quite hard to explain so I made a video for a better understanding: [Example Video](https://gofile.io/d/L3zMuY)

The way I am adding the `Cells` is quite complex so feel free to ask any questions if anything is unclear:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WhishCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! WhishCell

    let currentWish = self.wishData[indexPath.row]

    cell.label.text = currentWish.name

    cell.linkLabel.text = currentWish.link
    cell.priceLabel.text = currentWish.price
    cell.noteLabel.text = currentWish.note
    cell.wishImage.image = currentWish.image

    cell.setupLoadingAnimation()

    // reset height constraint

    cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.secondaryStackView.isHidden = true
    cell.thrirdStackViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.thirdStackView.isHidden = true

    cell.imageContainerWidthConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.imageContainerHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.wishImageWidthConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.imageContainerView.isHidden = true

    cell.priceView.isHidden = true
    cell.priceViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.linkView.isHidden = true
    cell.linkViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
    cell.noteView.isHidden = true
    cell.noteViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0


    if currentWish.image.hasContent {
        cell.secondaryStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.rowHeightThirdStackView * 3
        cell.imageContainerView.isHidden = false

        let ratio = currentWish.image.size.width / currentWish.image.size.height
        cell.wishImage.image = currentWish.image
        cell.wishImageWidthConstraint.constant = ratio * cell.wishImageHeight
        cell.imageContainerWidthConstraint.constant = cell.wishImageWidthConstraint.constant + 10
        cell.imageContainerHeightConstraint.constant = cell.rowHeightThirdStackView * 3
        cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = cell.wishImageHeight
    }

    if currentWish.price != "" {
        cell.priceView.isHidden = false
        cell.priceViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.rowHeightThirdStackView

        cell.secondaryStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.thirdStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += cell.rowHeightThirdStackView
        cell.thrirdStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += cell.rowHeightThirdStackView
    }

    if currentWish.link != "" {
        cell.linkView.isHidden = false
        cell.linkViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.rowHeightThirdStackView

        cell.secondaryStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.thirdStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += cell.rowHeightThirdStackView
        cell.thrirdStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += cell.rowHeightThirdStackView
    }

    if currentWish.note != "" {
        cell.noteView.isHidden = false
        cell.noteViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.rowHeightThirdStackView

        cell.secondaryStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.thirdStackView.isHidden = false
        cell.secondaryStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += cell.rowHeightThirdStackView
        cell.thrirdStackViewHeightConstraint.constant += cell.rowHeightThirdStackView
    }


    // tapping the checkbox in the wish cell will call back here
    // and we tell the delegate to delete the wish
    cell.deleteWishCallback = {
        self.deleteWishDelegate?.deleteWish(indexPath)
    }

    return cell
}
```

The important part of the code is `if currentWish.image.hasContent`. That is where I add the image.

I don't see why it is doing the animation so if anyone has any idea why this happens I am very grateful!

Comment: Chris! I can help if you're not busy now

Comment: @RobertCrabtree hey rob! I am actually not, lets chat then

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212810/room-for-chris-and-rob